# Trouble using branded keys together with object spread?

Tags: typescript

I'm using branded strings as keys in an object, and I'm running into a strange situation where TypeScript fails to flag what I think are pretty clear type errors.

A minimal reproduction of my problem:

```js
type SpecialKey = string & {__SpecialKey: true};

type SpecialKeysToStrings = {
  [key: SpecialKey]: string;
}

// This works
const obj1: SpecialKeysToStrings = {
  ['myKey' as SpecialKey]: "string",
};

// Value is not string; compiler catches this problem
const obj2: SpecialKeysToStrings = {
  ['myKey' as SpecialKey]: 100,
};

// Value is not string; compiler fails to catch this problem
const obj3: SpecialKeysToStrings = {
  ...{},
  ['myKey' as SpecialKey]: 100,
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=4&pln=2&pc=1#code/N4WAUABBAuCeAOBTCBlJBjAlgQwDYGlFYIBeCAZ2gCdMA7AcwgDIJgB9NtRLPQ2ALhhUArogC%20AbnDgocJKgw4CRcgBUA9imp165UqxlQIAbQDWRQVx7LYAXUGUaDKZAhjprgPSeIqgBaYegDu6lSm5Ibo6rSUEOoARgBWAIyWirwqGlpOuvqgrlDGAOQAtrB8RRDYelZKfPYQAESOOo0ANIaSHlDeEABqeKIQgRC06tAU2s4QUSXwmLiIVDPY0Oh%20iHrQAXrwVAmLJZHRsQmJAExp3HWZmlO5ZPlGJqXlRJXVCtcZdoLJAAz-DquLpgQy9Aa4IYjMYTFrTWbzRbLEYAeXwECCmG2w2gxxiEzOAGYrtY%20Go7jk9I9DFAAHQM4BiYHPYplCpVGrpGwNAFAzrgdxgsBPCC9ABioQgVEQADMlohaOhEG0YDthuRaEUJtgIHsDogSpjsX5RtEALTxKjYWgAE0Qtog5lgEWFsgQyAAcqESj8KdkdNSDAUTM6HPcGvD6C4oELwT5-CMQmFXVAogS4klUhBvVRfTZ-fcg6KoK8KoJmvd2p0XPH%20oNkDDxpMchIZuo5gslis1hstur9fFDvjTklLjmfX6skW8rSIGX3n9ASy3LWvD5IdC9LCWzo24iu8t0Kt1ps1SNB8PXOnR4kSRO81PKYHZyGGXSmSvS%20zFxA%20SuhTEIA)

For some reason, in the case of `obj3`, the use of an object spread before `['myKey' as SpecialKey]: 100` (which should be a type error) causes the compiler not to notice.

This seems to only occur when *both*:

1. a branded type is used as a key, and
2. an object spread is present.

Removing either of these factors causes TypeScript to behave in a correct way.

Am I missing something? Is this correct behavior? By using branded types, have I gone outside the realm where I can expect TypeScript to behave correctly? Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: This is [ms/TS#27273](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27273). When you write `{[x as SpecialKey]: 100}` you get an *index signature*, and that is currently dropped when you spread, so it loses track.  It's considered a feature request, not a bug.  Personally I'd say using branded types brings out outside the realm where you can expect TS to behave *how you want*; whether that's "correct" is debatable. There's also [ms/TS#43852](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43852) which is not considered a bug. Does this fully address the q? If so I'll write up an a; if not, what's missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! Those pointers are helpful. My general take-away is that spreading objects with index signatures isn't particularly well-supported by TypeScript, and I should probably avoid doing it. Sounds like an answer to me; feel free to post as such and I'll accept it!

(FWIW, I realized my situation could be handled fine with a `Map`, so that's what I'm doing now.)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript really isn't expecting you to use [branded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) as keys like this. A lot of things go wrong or weird along the way.

---

If you use a [computed key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) where the key's type is anything but a single [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then the key type will be widened all the way to a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
const o = { ['myKey' as SpecialKey]: 100 };
//    ^? const o: { [x: string]: number; }
```

This is considered a bug, raised at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948), but it's been around for a long time and there's no sign that it will be addressed.  This means that the game is already over; certainly the information you've tried to capture about the key type is lost. But it gets worse.

---

If you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) something into an object that has an index signature, TypeScript silently drops the index signature:

```
const o = { ...{}, ['myKey' as SpecialKey]: 100 };
//    ^? const o: {}
```

This part isn't considered a bug, but it is a missing feature requested at [microsoft/TypeScript#27273](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27273). But it exacerbates your problem. At least the type `{[x: string]: number}` is incompatible with `{[x: SpecialKey]: string}`, but `{}` is compatible with almost everything.

---

But there's more. Even if TypeScript does keep track of the branded type keys, it doesn't really care much about them:

```
let o: { [x: SpecialKey]: string } = { ["myKey" as SpecialKey]: "abc" };
type MundaneKey = string & { __SpecialKey: false };
let p: { [x: MundaneKey]: string } = { ["yourKey" as MundaneKey]: "abc" };
o = p; // okay
p = o; // okay
```

The fact that those are mutually assignable is a problem for your approach even if the above two issues were fixed/implemented.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#43852](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43852), which is considered another feature request.

Branded types are, as mentioned in [a comment by the TS team dev leap on microsoft/TypeScript#43852](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43852#issuecomment-828806813), "already a bit of an abuse and it's arguable that the current behavior is correct".

---

So there you go.  Computed properties, object spread, and branded keys all have issues that prevent this from working how you want, and most of those issues are not considered bugs in TypeScript.  You would do well to refactor away from branded keys and toward some other approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypDGBLAhgGwNIRFAvFAzsAE6IB2A5lAGRQDeUA+g3BEmpiAFxTECu0AXwDcAWABQ40JFgIUGLPgAqAexjEy5fLjrioUANoBrLNxZt5IALrdCJCqLEDx42rqjxlpQlGXb6+gHIAWxAOAKhkLTM5DmsoAEYABkSoYTcAenS9PQA9AH53T29lbn8ADxt1CjjSXiCAIwgiIVTxJwkxVzE9Dy9gHz8oADoR2gEAGgNg0KxwyJlWGKw4pJS07qhM7Kh8wr6fUvb2lzdUCH6SugMKhfNYyrtKAUH9ACIQjleIqNl2Ze5Xsh6vAvus9FJoABZXikAAmyFIEA42lsGmoVyY0T+XCgADM0PhBA49Gd+mBStduNC4Qikf8CFUni9XiBlLwiJ9vlBqfDEfcoIDgaDiQM8GAWltlIZkCA3GBtMoJVkpTK2s4OkA)